# Power BI: To show incremental day by sale when there is no sale in that date

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am facing on Power BI to calculate gross income by incremental day. There is no data on Jan 11, 2019, but on Power BI, need to show gross in come on Jan 11, 2019 as picture stated below. Please help on modeling step. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGR9t.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need a date table/ date dimension.

Comment: Don’t you think it would be great to add some samples for calendar table CALENDARAUTO etc…?

Comment: Possibly but the whole idea of having a date dimension is PBI 101 and I think what the user really needs to do is some basic tutorials and some self-teaching.